# Error in installing React - incompatible engine

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So after typing

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

I get this error

```
error eslint@8.15.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^12.22.0 || ^14.17.0 || >=16.0.0". Got "12.13.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
 
 
Aborting installation.
yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd /Users/theodosiostziomakas/Desktop/React Tutorial and Project Course (2022)/01_React Basics Tutorial/my-app has failed.
 
 
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting my-app/ from /Users/theodosiostziomakas/Desktop/React Tutorial and Project Course (2022)/01_React Basics Tutorial
Done.
```

How to update the node engine? Could it be something else?

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: Your version of Node is too old. Update it by installing a more up-to-date version or use something like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#node-version-manager---) to manage multiple versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says your current version of node is 12.13.0 and you need at least 12.22.0.

The current version of Node is 16.15.0
You can download an updated one at https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 2):

You're using a wrong version of node.

IMHO the best way to manage the node version is using **nvm**.

Nvm is a tool used to switch easy the node version.

[Unix version](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)
[Windows version](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

In your case you have to:

- Uninstall node
- install nvm
- `nvm install 12.13.0`
- `nvm install 16.15.0`
- `nvm use 16.15.0`
- try again `npx create-react-app myapp`